# Use both losses on a subnetwork of combined networks

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to stack two networks together. I want to calculate loss of each network separately. For example in the image below; loss of LSTM1 should be *(Loss1 + Loss2)* and loss of system should be just *(Loss2)*

[image: stacked networks]

I implemented a network like below with the idea above but have no idea how to compile and run it.

```
def build_lstm1():
    x = Input(shape=(self.timesteps, self.input_dim,), name = 'input')
    h = LSTM(1024, return_sequences=True))(x)
    scores = TimeDistributed(Dense(self.input_dim, activation='sigmoid', name='dense'))(h)
    LSTM1 = Model(x, scores)
    return LSTM1


def build_lstm2():
    x = Input(shape=(self.timesteps, self.input_dim,), name = 'input')
    h = LSTM(1024, return_sequences=True))(x)
    labels = TimeDistributed(Dense(self.input_dim, activation='sigmoid', name='dense'))(h)
    LSTM2 = Model(x, labels)
    return LSTM2




lstm1 = build_lstm1()
lstm2 = build_lstm2()


combined = Model(inputs = lstm1.input ,
                 outputs = [lstm1.output,
                            lstm2(lstm1.output).output)])
```

Comment: Can you give a detailed result of above network. What is the result of above network after feeding inputs properly?

Comment: Feseoglu, here is a keras tutorial page https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models for your problem. Please inform us if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong way of using the Model functional API of Keras. Also it's not possible to have loss of LSTM1 as Loss1+ Loss2. It will be only Loss1. Similarly for LSTM2 it will be only Loss2. However, for the combined network you can have any linear combination of Loss1 and Loss2 as the overall Loss i.e.

Loss_overall = a.Loss1 + b.Loss2. where a,b are non-negative real numbers

The real essence of Model Functional API is that it allows you create Deep learning architecture with multiple outputs and multiple inputs in single model.

```
def build_lstm_combined():
    x = Input(shape=(self.timesteps, self.input_dim,), name = 'input')
    h_1 = LSTM(1024, return_sequences=True))(x)
    scores = TimeDistributed(Dense(self.input_dim, activation='sigmoid', name='dense'))(h_1)
    h_2 = LSTM(1024, return_sequences=True))(h_1)
    labels = TimeDistributed(Dense(self.input_dim, activation='sigmoid', name='dense'))(h_2)
    LSTM_combined = Model(x,[scores,labels])
    return LSTM_combined
```

This combined model has loss which is combination of both Loss1 and Loss2. While compiling the model you can specify the weights of each loss to get overall loss. If your desired loss is 0.5Loss1 + Loss2 you can do this by:

```
model_1 = build_lstm_combined()
model_1.compile(optimizer=Adam(0.001), loss = ['categorical_crossentropy','categorical_crossentropy'],loss_weights= [0.5,1])
```

Comment: As Loss2, I meant the loss of system. I edited my question now, so now the loss of lstm1 should be model loss and lstm1 loss, loss of lstm2 should come from the models loss.

Comment: I don't know why you would want loss of LSTM 1 and LSTM 2 separately since there are part of one big model. As far as training of any neural network no matter how complex or for that matter any ML model, there is only one loss. Loss, as in our case, may be combination of different parts (Loss = loss1 + loss2) but during we try to to minimise the overall loss to get optimum weight parameters.  I think by loss you mean intermediate output from LSTM 1 which is reflected in my answer.